# Saving randomly selected SQL data to then edit later?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, session-variables

```
    <?php 
$user_name = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "words";
    $server = "127.0.0.1";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);

    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    $randWordDesc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($randWordDesc);

    if (isset($_POST['new'])) {

        $unaltered = $db_field['noun'];
        $lower=strtolower($unaltered);

        $stepsinchain = array($lower);


        if (isset($_POST['A'])) {
            $subo = str_replace("o", "A", end($stepsinchain));
            $stepsinchain[] = $subo;
        }
        if (isset($_POST['E'])) {
            $subi = str_replace("i", "E", end($stepsinchain));
            $stepsinchain[] = $subi;
        }
    }
?>
<form action="http://localhost/subsite/subletter.php" method="post" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="A"> A for o 
    <input type="checkbox" name="E"> E for i

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="new" value = "new" >
</form>
```

I have some code that will pull a random word from my SQL database with the substitions that are checked.
But after I pull that word, I'd like to be able have another option to check some boxes, hit enter, and thesame word comes back with the substitutions I checked instead of just generating another random word with the checked substitutions.
To do this, I think I need someway of storing the original random query and then making the edits on it. Is this the way to go? What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: What does the table  `words` look like? If there is an `id` or `PRIMARY KEY` field, can you use that?

Comment: You don't need to store the original random query, just the ID's of the results.

Comment: how would i use the id to store it?